# Nice way to call a method of a property

Tags: python, methods, properties, call

Imagine the following code (which is totally useless if taken alone):

```
# define a property with additional methods
class P(property):
    def __init__(self, name):
        property.__init__(self, 
            fget=lambda self: self._get(name),
            fset=lambda self, v: self._set(name, v))
        self._name = name

    def some_fn(self):
        print('name: ' + self._name)

# define a class with two 'enhanced' properties
class C:
    p1 = P('p1')
    p2 = P('p2')

    def __init__(self):
        self._values = {}

    def _get(self, name):
        return self._values[name]

    def _set(self, name, v):
        self._values[name] = v

c = C()

c.p1 = 5
c.p2 = c.p1

print(c.p1, c.p2)
```

I just create a class `C` with two `properties` which have an extra method `some_fn()`.

The problem is now: you can't call `some_fn()` easily by just writing `c.p1.some_fn()` because you would evaluate `c.p1` first, which results in some value which doesn't provide the method any more.

I've tried to find some workarounds / approaches for calling `some_fn` in the context of a `certain property`, not it's value but I'm not happy yet.

My goal is quite simple:

- I want to be able read/assign properties without boilerplate:
  `c.p1 = c.p2` instead of `c.p1.set(c.p2.get())`
- The way I call the extra method/function must be easy to read/write
- I want to write code that can be statically verified by `pylint`, `mypy` etc. so `some_fn('c.p1') is not an option because it can't be checked whether 'c.p1' is a valid attribute of an existing object`c`.
- `some_fn` doesn't *have to be* a method. It can be a function or any other way to request functionality in context of a property
- I don't even need *real* `properties`. Any other way to write s.th.
  like `c.p1 == c.p2` (e.g. using `__getattr__`/`__setattr__`) would be fine, too as long as the get/set operations are still trackable.

I collected some code to make clear, what I'm talking about:

```
# ==== What I want to do ==============
c.p1.some_fn()              #  <-- this is what I want to write but
                            #      it's invalid since it evaluates to
                            #      5.some_fn()

some_fn(c.p1)               #  <-- something like this looks OK, too but
                            #      it evalueates to some_fn(5) (useless)

# ==== These are options that came to mind but I'm not happy with ======

getattr(C, 'p1').some_fn()  #  <-- this works but it is ugly

some_fn("c.p1")             #  <-- this is possible, too but I can't 
                            #      check integrity statically (pylint/mypy)

c.p1.value = c.p2.value     #  <-- this is a valid approach but it 
c.p1.some_fn()              #      increases

some_fn(c.p1)  # (again)    #  <-- This can acutally work if you `inspect`
                            #      the call stack inside `C._get()` but 
                            #      it's black magic and incredibly slow

with some_fn():             #  <-- this can work when `some_fn` changes 
    c.p1                    #      some global state which get's evaluated
                            #      inside `C._get()`
```

Comment: What do you want the methods like `some_fn` to do?  Why do you need them?  Your proposed example of using something like `c.p1.value` is the only one that can really work.  There's no way you can get `c.p1` to evaluate to 5, while also allowing `c.p1.some_fn()`.  It sounds like you need to customize the *values* that get assigned to the properties, not the property objects themselves.

Answer (score 1):

> My goal is quite simple: I want to be able read/assign properties without boilerplate: `c.p1 = c.p2`

If that is the goal here, it sounds like you've misunderstood properties, because they already work like that.

```
class C(object):
    @property
    def p1(self):
        # get value
    @p1.setter
    def p1(self, val):
        # set value

    @property
    def p2(self):
        # get value
    @p2.setter
    def p2(self, val):
        # set value
```

Then if you have an object `c = C()`, you can do `c.p1 = c.p2`, and it'll just work. Sticking more methods onto a `property` object is the wrong way to go.

---

If you really want to stick methods onto properties, retrieve the property through the class:

```
C.p1.some_fn()
```

Comment: I don't insist on using properties and I don't actually *need* to add methods to properties. My goal is to use expressions like `c.p1` or `component_x.subcomponent_y.parameter_z` which I can use like native data types AND to do things like `observe(c.p1)` or `add_dependency(c.p1, c.p2)` (these are only examples for *operations* on named elements in a tree)

Comment: @frans: Yeah, that's just too counter to Python's evaluation model to work. It'd work in something like R, but not Python. Given what you've already considered, the best I can come up with is making separate `p1_link` and `p2_link` properties that evaluate to something representing "the p1 property of this object", so `observe(c.p1_link)` would observe `c.p1`.

Comment: Currently I'm just looking for a not-too-creepy workaround - I've fiddled with the `inspect` approach but that was way too slow in the end (about 8ms per call). I'll give your approach a try - it doesn't touch the rest of the implementation and thus it's very flexible

Comment: @frans: As user2357112 says, you're never going to be able to get exactly that.  Whatever `c.p1` evaluates to, it has to evaluate to the same thing in an expression like `c.p1 + 2` as it does in `observe(c.p1)`.  I think the simplest thing is to just make your properties return objects with a `value` attribute or the like.  The extra time you spend typing `c.p1.value` will be far less than you'd spend trying to make more complicated solutions work.